# How to suppress a short circuit to prevent fuses from blowing

Tags: protection, short-circuit, circuit-protection

I have a circuit that is modular and one of the modules involves interfacing from an external relay.

Now this sub-module has a fuse set to blow a bit below what the main module's max current. (why put a fuse when the main module has over current protection? So that when this sub module fails it wont take the whole system down with it) This sub modules can cater upto 24 external relays and in the image below i will be showing how one channel is setup

What i would like to protect is the fuse from blowing from a false short circuit(not really false, since it is doing its job) in the cenario that the user might incorrectly wire the connection and shorts pin A and pin B. I need a current limiting solution so that the fuse wont blow up and the user of the sub module can rewire and try again.

[image]

The circuit is designed to trigger one relay at a time, a signal will be sent by a portexpander(not shown in picture) to the bs138 mosfet to open. the signal typically last around 250ms - 1000ms.

I have considered a polyfuse but it to slow to react the main module protection will trip first. Another is adding a resistor in series with the relay line but it is either a bulky high watt rated resistor or a high value resistor that might not make the relay trigger because of voltage drop.

there is also the problem since there is a short the power to the sub-micro controller will be cut, so this protection circuit i am looking for would probably happen in either series or parallel of the connection for the external relay

I need current limiting solution between pin A and pin B so that when A and B is shorted by the user and the mosfet turns on the fuse wont blow

how do you recommend to solve this problem, Thank you.

Comment: The reason the sub module has a fuse is because the main module overcurrent protection might be too high to protect the wiring and external components on the far side. For example, the main module overcurrent trip threshold might be set for its total output current and if it's supply multiple modules, that current is going to be far higher than what any single module can handle.

Comment: why are you asking this question again?

Comment: Aside: I hope there is a freewheeling diode across each relay coil.

Comment: @DKNguyen this is my own circuit :D  my problem is i need someway to prevent the fuse from blowing because a user erronously shorted the relay outputs of the submodule and turning the transistor on causing a short. i only want the fuse to blow by a short on the other components

Comment: @jsotola i need to the fuse to not blow by accident, ( comment above )

Comment: @rdtsc can you elaborate? The external components are not in my control. If i place  a diode parallel to the Led+resistor wont the shortcircuit still happen?

Comment: What type of "false short circuit" are you talking about? It sounds like you're talking about an *actual* short circuit. How would the fuse know the difference between some short circuits and other short circuits? And the wiring doesn't care either, if you remove the fuse and create a short circuit, then your board might catch fire even if you don't think it should "count" as a short circuit... the universe doesn't care whether you think things "shouldn't count"...

Comment: @user253751 that the point of why i am asking the question, i need something to suppress the short circuit on pinA and pinB so that the user of the module can rewire and try again. Also do not worry the board wont catch fire, the overcurrent protection from the main module will prevent that.

Comment: Jake, if you do not have a diode across pins A and B (anode to B) then when the relay is powered off, it's stored magnetic field will instantly collapse, generating a large negative voltage spike. This is likely to exceed the LED's reverse breakdown voltage at least.

Comment: @rdtsc thank you for that suggestion, i will put the diode in the circuit.  Since we are on the topic what diode specs should i look for in choosing this diode? Are there preferred types?

Comment: No special specs required for a flyback diode. 1N4004,5,6,7 or similar surface-mount equivalents would all be fine.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have described an application for a slow-blow fuse or a Polyfuse to heat up faster than the load. These tend to operate between 85’C and 125’C by design.

A better design would define that actual load V vs I and Fault current then define limitations for cost and area. It might be feasible to use a 5.5V to 6Vdc input with  a 3 terminal regulator with OCP,OTP and UVLO with say 0.4V dropout at 1A for only $0.80 (100pc) in a SOT-223 package e.g. [MCP1826ST-5002E/DB](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MCP1826ST-5002E-DB/MCP1826ST-5002E-DBCT-ND/9643006)
[image]

Intelligent auto-resettable breakers need accurate specs for break and retry algorithms.
 - But for thermal loads such as motors used to close car windows, a thermal switch is used that acts quicker than the motor to cut off power but takes just as long as the motor to cool off and retry power again.  this can be something like 1 sec OFF and 5 to 10 sec ON retry.  This usually uses a carefully selected polyfuse controlled relay.

**Also replace the main fuse with a slow blow fuse.**

Comment: If you are talking about the main fuse, i would not like it to blow because the user accidentally shorted pin A and B. I would like something that make it so that when pin A and B is shorted and the mosfets turns on  the sub module will still remain functional and the user can try again.

Comment: "user accidentally shorted pin A and B" is EXACTLY the kind of situation the fuse is supposed to protect from. Polyfuse should be perfect for this situation

Comment: @Maple yes the fuse is doing its job, but i would not want the user to keep replacing the fuse, the polyfuse is supposedly the perfect option but the fastest poly fuse i could find trips at 100ms, both the main fuse and the main module overcurent protecton trips way before that

Comment: @Jakequin Can you define your design better please? Why not use Current sensing? or a heat sink to delay temp rise.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 although current sensing is an option , it requires several parts,  multiply that by 24 channels and it kinda adds up, i unfortunatly dont have the luxury of board space.  Heatsink wont work since the overcurrent protection on the main module is not temperature based so it would trip at a certain current.

Comment: "both the main fuse and the main module overcurent protecton trips way before that" ... and what is wrong with that? You are talking about incorrect wiring scenario, which can happen only once and on inactive system. If you consider connecting on live system then you __must__ use plugs/jacks instead of pins.

Comment: Thank you i did not notice the addition of an IC to you comment, i found a somewhat similar to what ou have commented [Link](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/TPS2065CDBVR/296-39353-1-ND/5143305) and has a bit more features,

Answer (score 2):

The fuse wouldn't be blowing by accident.  The fuse would be blowing because it's passing too much current.  I don't really understand what you're asking.  The fuse SHOULD blow if you short it.  If you don't need it to do that, you should replace it with a wire.  If you don't want it to blow specifically from a short between A and B, you can move the fuse somewhere else, or put some sort of minimal load  or current limiting device between A and B.

Comment: Yes that is what i really ment, i am looking for something to put between A and B so that that when the user accidentally short A and B the fuse wont blow up. can you recommend a good current limiting solution ?

Comment: Personally, I would consider a resistor.

Comment: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/mosfet-current-limiter.132755/

Comment: if you also think a resistor is a good solution. which would you prefer a high watt bulky resistor or a high value resistor. The relay is 5v assuming a relay eats up of a max 100mA  you need a 0.5watt  5 ohms (limit to 1 amps) or  a high resistance (enough that the voltage that reaches to the relay is around 4.5v)

Answer (score 0):

> I need a way to prevent a short circuit from ever happening on the
>   outputs of the sub module no matter how the user mess up the
>   connection to the external relays.

The only way to minimize the chance of this happening is to use **polarized shrouded connectors** instead of pins.

Any attempt to bypass or disable the fuse only defeats the purpose of having it. There is no protection from the stupid and reducing the error coverage only increases chances for failures.

Comment: I like designing in mind that the most stupid user will use it. I am currently leaning to adding a 5ohm 1watt resistor in series with  either pin A or B. so that when it is shorted out the 5 ohm resistor will draw 1A of current.

Comment: Jake Define actual load for voltage and current in your question